# Compare two alike fields from two separate models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, orm

Given django 1.8, python 2.7.5, postgresql and the following generic models:

```
class restAPI(models.Model):
    rest_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rest_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rest_mode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rest_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class soapAPI(models.Model):
    soap_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

In a perfect world `soapAPI.soap_host` and `restAPI.rest_host` will match perfectly. However that is rarely the case. I am trying to find and return any hosts that are present in soapAPI that are not in restAPI. I have a working method currently where I parse this data using python prior to saving it to it's own model in django, but I have to believe that I can do this using the models themselves (which I would think would be more efficient as well).

How can one return the *ENTIRE* model of `soapAPI` where `soapAPI.soap_host` is missing in `restAPI.rest_host` using the orm provided by django or using `.raw()`, ,preferably with the orm? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated as this is a learning experience for me. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT1**

Completely open to model relationships as some form of an answer as well.

**EDIT2**

Leaving open as I have to believe there is a better way to do this than multiple querysets.

**EDIT3**

Additionally is there a way to do muiltiple `__in`'s or something? I actually need to return the entire `soapAPI` model where `soapAPI.soap_host` is missing in `restAPI.rest_host` *AND* `soapAPI.soap_state` is 'Live'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I could come up with given the answer that @HassenPy gave:

```
excludehosts = restAPI.objects.values_list('rest_host', flat=True)
missinghosts = soapAPI.objects.exclude(soap_host__in=excludehosts)
```

**EDIT**

To answer my own edit 3, this is the best I could come up with:

```
excludehosts = restAPI.objects.values_list('rest_host', flat=True)
missinghosts = soapAPI.objects.exclude(soap_host__in=excludehosts)
missinghosts.filter(soap_state='Live')
```

Though the following works as well:

```
excludehosts = restAPI.objects.values_list('rest_host', flat=True)
soapAPI.objects.filter(soap_state='Live').exclude(soap_host__in=excludehosts)
```

Not sure which is technically better since I can't honestly decern a difference in return time, but hey working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

> ```
> rest_hosts = restAPI.objects.only("rest_host")
> excluded_rest_hosts = [host.rest_host for host in rest_hosts]
> missing_soap_hosts = soapAPI.objects.exclude(soap_host__in=excluded_rest_hosts)
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for whatever reason I am getting this: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'rest_host' into field. Choices are: id, soap_asset, soap_host, soap_id, soap_state`

Comment: Figured it out and in less code. See my answer. Thank you for getting me started though, you're help was instrumental. now if I could only figure out how to do this in one queryset.

Comment: i don't see any answer O.o

Comment: You are looking for a solution with 1 `queryset` or 1 `query` ? Because the one you posted *(with the `values_list`)* is already a 1 `query` solution.

Comment: @Todor Sorry, Trying for 1 queryset if at all possible.